# Not getting ACTION_UP or ACTION_MOVE in onTouch()

Tags: android

In RelativeLayout, i want to move a view. But in onTouch() only ACTION_DOWN is getting hit. I am not able to get ACTION_MOVE or ACTION_UP. Below is the code snippet.

```
 private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
         switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            log("onTouch motion event ACTION_DOWN ");

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            log("onTouch motion event ACTION_MOVE ");

                break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            log("onTouch motion event ACTION_UP ");

                break;

               }
         return true;
     } 
 }
```

Need help....

Answer (score 0):

write  `return false;` rather  `return true;` in `onTouch();` method;

**UPDATE**

```
switch(event.getAction()){
}
```

Comment: I had below logs in onTouch event, but both are same.. "  log("onTouch motion event: " + motionEvent.getAction());
  log("onTouch motion masked event: " + motionEvent.getActionMasked());"